# Transistor amplifier circuit for triangular wave

Tags: transistors, pwm, oscillator

I've made triangular wave oscilator as shown in Fig. 1 and it works perfectly at frequancy 10 kHz with peak voltage +3 Volt to -3 Volt.

[image: Figure 1. Oscilator circuit]

I intend to generate SPWM. But when I feed this circuit to comparator, the output drops to 0 Volt. How can this happen?

[image]

I assume that output current of op-amp IC TL-082 is very small, not enough to feed comparator. If my assumption is correct, can I use transistor amplifier to produce enough current?

Comment: Th comparator should have very high impedance inputs, so the problem must be something else. Did you measured the waveform on the second opamp with comparator connected? how is the - input of the comparator connected?

Comment: The oscilator output is +3 to -3 Volt. When connected to comparator, the oscilator output drops 0 Volt.

Comment: The comparator does not need any input current - however, what about the inverting termoinal - open?

Comment: Have you tested the comparator alone? The TL082 should be abe to source/sink at least 1.4mA, that should be more than enough for the comparator.

Comment: You don't mention what comparator you're using, but feeding negative input signals into a comparator with only a positive supply is typically not acceptable.

Comment: What Spehro said! Does this oscillator work by railing the opamp?  (What does it look like when it leaves the rail?)  I wonder if a comparator would be better than the first opamp?

Comment: @LvW Inverting terminal connected to 1 Volt - 50 Hz sine wave. Comparator cant generate spwm because oscilator output is 0 Volt.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira and Spehro Can I use TL082 for comparator, with -Vcc connected to ground, and +Vcc connected to +5 Volt DC supply?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Positive input connected to oscilator and negative input to 1 Volt 50 Hz sine wave. Comparator cant generate SPWM because oscilator has 0 V output.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I dont know about that. This oscilator works fine with a 10 kOhm resistor connected to the output.

Comment: @Sidqi If you connect -Vcc to 0V and +Vcc to +5V you may need to connect the - input of the first opamp to 2.5V, you can use a voltage divider with 2 resistors of the same value to accomplish this.

Comment: It's the compartor power supply connected to ground that's the problem.  (Put the 10 k ohm resistor in series at the output of the integrator.)

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Does it change the oscilator's output?

Comment: @Sidqi I'm not sure, you'll have to try.

Comment: Is this a simulation or a real circuit? What are you using for your comparator and are you sure about its pin numbering?

Comment: @brhans Real circuit. I use TL082 as comparator with negative supply (-Vcc) connected to ground directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> I use TL082 as comparator with negative supply (-Vcc) connected to ground directly.

In the [datasheet for the TL082](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082-n.pdf), under `APPLICATION HINTS`, it clearly states:

> However, neither of the input voltages should be allowed to exceed the negative supply as this will cause large currents to flow which can result in a destroyed unit.

Your integrating opamp, `IC(2/2)`, is using a bipolar supply, and the output signal swings both positive and negative. However, when you connect this signal to the third opamp, which has V<sub>EE</sub> connected to ground, the signal gets clamped at ground. This is because when it tries to go below ground, the third opamp allows a "large current to flow" (i.e., its input impedance drops dramatically). This stops the oscillation, because now the first opamp, `IC(1/2)`, can't switch at -3V like it normally does.

The solution is to connect V<sub>EE</sub> of the third opamp to the same negative supply as the other opamps. Why didn't you do this to begin with?

Comment: Already did. I got SPWM output with peak values +Vsat and -Vsat. Thank you.